# Angularjs default action when Enter key is pressed

Tags: angularjs

My understanding with forms, is that if the form has an ng-submit action associated with it, then pressing the Enter key would invoke that action, typically mimicking the click of the form's "submit" button. I have a form that does not have have a button, but a custom image of a button within a div tag and the div tag has the ng-click action. When I press Enter, nothing happens.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make your button type `submit` and add a class attribute and style your button to make it an image like:

```
<form ng-submit="someAction()">
 <button type="submit" class="submitbutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And do style your button in css like:

```
.submitbutton {
  background:url('....') // your custom image
}
```

Then your custom image will act as the submit button and invoke the form action when click the enter key.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning here is that the default type for a button is type="submit". If you have multiple buttons within your form that have ng-click actions, Angular will perform all of them sequentially unless you add `<button type="button" ...>` to your non-submit buttons.

Comment: In Angular 7, one uses:
    (ngSubmit)="someAction()"
instead of:
    ng-submit="someAction()"

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me by adding ng-submit, ng-controller & button type as submit

`<form ng-submit="func()" ng-controller="MyController">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button
</form>`

Answer (score 1):

if your form contains **md-autofocus** - remove it.
worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 13:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="search()">
    <input type="text" id="inputword" />
    <button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
```